# Use negate ^ to get results which not contain specified charactres

Tags: grep, filenames

I want to grep the files whose name not containing `"^iX500"`

```
$ cat note_list 
...
/Applications/ScanSnap Manual.localized/iX500ScanSnapManual.app/Contents/Resources/manual/basic/EN/ix500/images_mac/EvernoteMark.png
/Applications/ScanSnap
```

I tried

```
 cat note_list | grep -i "^iX500"
 #not return results
```

and

```
$ cat note_list | egrep -i "^(iX500)"
#not return result
```

Finally, I use the `-v` get it done

```
cat note_list | egrep -i -v "(iX500)"
```

but how could I use negate `^` in grep.

Comment: UUOC. Better: grep <search term> <filename>

Comment: Did you try `cat note_list | grep -i -v "iX500"` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using `grep` on filenames is that `grep` is a line-oriented tool, and filenames may contain newlines.

Assuming that all filenames in your file are without newlines, then you would use `grep -v` to negate sense of matching:

```
grep -iF -v 'iX500' <note_list
```

I've added `-F` since it's a string rather than a regular expression that we are matching with.

The `^` is used inside `[...]` to match a single character *not* in a particular set.  For example, `[^a-z]` would match a single character that is not a lower-case letter in the given range (assuming the standard POSIX locale).  When used elsewhere, `^` denotes the start of the string, so that e.g. `^alpha` matches the string `alpha` *only* at the start of a line (and likewise, `alpha$` would match the string only at the end of the line).

What I think you are looking for is to craft a regular expression that matches "not `iX500`".  The issue with this is that most of the strings in your example would match that.  For example, the bit that is `Applications` (on both lines in the example) is "not `iX500`".

The following extracts all lines that does not contain the letter `X`:

```
grep '^[^X]*$'
```

Instead of the "not `X`" expression `[^X]*`, in your case, you would have to come up with a regular expression that matches *the whole line* but which does not match the word `iX500` anywhere.

It's probably possible in some way with GNU `grep` and using a PCRE expression with look-ahead/behind, but it's much easier to just match `iX500` and then to negate the sense of the match with `-v`.

Comment: Also `grep -x '[^X]*'`. Note that with some `grep` implementations, it also skips the lines that contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters, so it's not strictly equivalent to `grep -v X` on invalid text input.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes.  The issue here is that I think the user want's to do everything within the expression itself, hence the question of how to do it without using `-v`.

Comment: ast _augmented_ regexps have a `!` negation operator, so with ast-open `grep` (or the `grep` builtin of ksh93 if built as part of ast-open), you can do `grep -Xix '(iX500)!'` (it skips empty lines though which looks like a bug).